# Execute a stored procedure in java with multiple parameters using spring

Tags: java, spring

I have to call a stored procedure with call statement.But the input parameter and output parameter may differ based on stored procedure.

The example query is `CALL Procedure_Name('448525','','',0,'','');`

448525 is an input parameter, and remaining all are output parameters.

How can I call this stored procedure with Java code?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [CallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html)

```
CallableStatement call = conn.prepareCall("{ call Procedure_Name('448525', ?, ?,0, ?) }");
```

Set input parameter as below

```
call.setInt(1, someParameterValue1);
call.setString(2, someParameterValue2);
```

Register the output params as below

```
call.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

Finally execute

```
call.executeUpdate();
```

Getting the output params:

```
String outputParam = call.getInt(3);
```

Comment: but the 448525 was only one input then the remaining 4 will be

Comment: @Jeeva you can register multiple out parameters as you want using `CallableStatement .registerOutParameter(int parameterIndex, int sqlType)` as mentioned in the answer